# Solve the equation $\log_{2} x \log_{3} x = \log_{4} x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

**Question:**

Solve the equations

a)
$$\log_{2} x + \log_{3} x = \log_{4} x$$

b)
$$\log_{2} x \log_{3} x = \log_{4} x$$

**Attempted solution:**

The general idea I have been working on is to make them into the same base, combine them and take the inverse to get the solution for x.

a)
$$\log_{2} x + \log_{3} x = \log_{4} x \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\log_{2} x + \frac{\log_{2} x}{\log_{2} 3} = \frac{\log_{2} x}{\log_{2} 4} \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\log_{2} x + \frac{\log_{2} x}{\log_{2} 3} = \frac{\log_{2} x}{2} \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\frac{2 \log_{2} 3 \log_{2}x + 2\log_{2} x - \log_{2}3 \log_{2}x}{2 \log_{2}3} = 0 \Leftrightarrow $$

Moving the denominator over and solving for $\log_{2} x$

$$\frac{\log_{2} x (2\log_{2}3 + 1 - \log_{2}3)}{2\log_{2} 3} = 0 \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\log_{2} x = 0 \Rightarrow x = 2^{0} = 1$$

b)

$$\log_{2} x \log_{3} x = \log_{4} x$$

$$\log_{2} x \frac{\log_{2} x}{\log_{2} 3} - \frac{\log_{2} x}{\log_{2} 4} = 0 \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\frac{4 (\log_{2}x)^2 - \log_{2}3 \log_{2}x}{4 \log_{2}3} = 0 \Leftrightarrow $$

$$4 (\log_{2}x)^2 - \log_{2}3 \log_{2}x = 0 \Leftrightarrow $$

Substituting $t = \log_{2} x$ gives:

$$4t^2 - \log_{2}3t = 0 \Rightarrow$$

$$t^2 - \frac{\log_{2}3t}{4} = 0 \Rightarrow$$

$$t \left(t- \frac{\log_{2}3}{4}\right) = 0$$

$$t_{1} = 0 \Rightarrow x = 1$$
$$t_{2} = \frac{\log_{2}3}{4} \Rightarrow x = 2^{\frac{\log_{2}3}{4}}$$

However, the second solution here should be $\sqrt{3}$, so I must have made a mistake somewhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: Raise $12$ to the power of both of these numbers and equate the two sides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your denominator of $4$ in $(b)$ is wrong - $\log_2(4)=2$, not $4$. Then you'd get:

$$2^{\frac{\log_2(3)}{2}} = \left(2^{\log_2(3)}\right)^{1/2}=3^{1/2}$$

It might be easier to just use that $\log_4{x}=\frac{\log_2(x)}{2}$ and solve:

$$\log_2(x)\log_3(x)=\frac{\log_2(x)}{2}$$

This is only true when $\log_2(x)=0$ or when $\log_3(x)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

rewrite the second equation as $$\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}\cdot\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(3)}= \frac{\ln(x)}{2\ln(2)}$$
and the first equation as
$$\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}+\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(3)}=\frac{\ln(x)}{2\ln(2)}$$

Comment: "First equation" is ambiguous here - there are two equations in the body of the question, and the one you've written is the second. But it is the title equation, so your label "first" is true in that sense. However, given that the equations in the body are labeled (a) and (b), perhaps you could just use those labels?

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake in part (b) is on line three where you replaced $\log_24$ with $4$ when it should be replaced by $2$

Answer (score 0):

One solution is apparent for (a): $x=1$. There can be no other solutions, since the two sides' derivatives are $\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{\ln(2)}+\frac{1}{\ln(3)}\right)>\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\ln(4)}<\frac{1}{x}$. This shows us that the left side is always growing at a faster rate than the right side, so at most one solution is possible.

For (b), $x=1$ is also an apparent solution. But it's not the only one. Raising $4$ to both sides leaves $$x^{2\log_3(x)}=x\implies x^{2\log_3(x)-1}=1\quad\text{(since $x\ne0$)}$$

So $\ln(x)\cdot(2\log_3(x)-1)=0$. Either $x=1$ to make the first factor $0$, or $2\log_3(x)-1=0$ to make the second factor $0$. The latter option implies $x=3^{1/2}$. So the only two possible solutions are $x=1$ and $x=\sqrt{3}$, both of which check out to actually be solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you made two mistakes.

The first mistake is in a) when factorizing, instead you typed it should have been $\frac{\log_{2} x(2\log_{2} 3+ 2 -\log_{2} 3)}{2\log_{2} 3}=0$ though it doesn´t affect the answer.

And the other mistake in b) is the one that @Gregory Grant says, once you do that you get to answer $x=\sqrt 3$